# Split on spaces except those within quotes but also allow escaped quotes

Tags: regex, string, split, escaping

If my input string is:

`Word "Two Words" Quo\"te "Quo\"ted Words"`

The output should be:

`Word` `Two Words` `Quo"te` `Quo"ted Words`.

I can't seem to work in the escaped quotes in my regex.

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 0):

split using this pattern `(?<!\\)".*?(?<!\\)"(*SKIP)(*F)|\s`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hC3bD1)